# Is there any inbuilt hashmap function to handle input by values in c++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

This is my input txt document:

```
Hello A:1
World A:1
Hello A:2
World A:2
Hello B:1
World B:2
Hello C:4
```

I tried to use like a loop hashmap in hashmap it didn’t help me. Here is my key and value for hashtable:

```
String word,word1,word2,word3,word4; // for example word1 is Hello, word2 is A:1
size_t sub1;
word = word1 + word2;   
sub1 = word.find(":");
word3 = word.substr(0,sub1+1); //word3 = "Hello A" which is my key for internal hash function 
word4 = word.substr(sub1+1,word.length()); //word4 = 1,2 which is word3's value.
```

Do you have any idea which inbuilt function I can use to get this output?

```
Hello A:1,2 B:1 C:4
World A:1,2 B:2
```

There are obviously better solutions and I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some ideas preferably with some code please ?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: If that output ordering is important, a hash table isn't going to do this, as it isn't necessarily ordered. A `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::set<int>>>` populated from your input data would probably do what you want. If the ordering isn't important. i.e World can come before Hello, B can come before A, and/or 2 can come before 1, then unordered_map and unordered_set can be used instead. Either way, a map of maps of sets would/should do what you want.

Comment: I could not think to use map like a key in another map :( Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the character before the colon is always a single uppercase character between A-Z, and that the order of the lines of output aren't important, you can use this solution.

```c++
int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> mmap;
  std::string line;
  std::stringstream stream;
  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    stream.str(line);
    std::string word;
    stream >> word;
    if (mmap.find(word) == mmap.end()) {
      mmap[word] = std::vector<std::string>(26);
    }
    char letter, sep;
    int num;
    stream >> letter >> sep >> num;
    std::string& entry = mmap[word][letter - 'A'];
    if (entry.empty())
      entry += std::to_string(num);
    else
      entry += "#" + std::to_string(num);
    stream.clear();
  }

  for (auto const& [word, record] : mmap) {
    std::cout << word << " ";
    const char* sep1 = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
      if (!record[i].empty()) {
        std::cout << sep1 << char(i + 'A') << ":";
        stream.str(record[i]);
        char const* sep2 = "";
        std::string num;
        while (std::getline(stream, num, '#')) {
          std::cout << sep2 << num;
          sep2 = ",";
        }
        sep1 = " ";
      }
      stream.clear();
      stream.str("");
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If the order *is* important you can simply change the `unordered_map` to `map`.

Comment: Why did you use letter - 'A' ?  and in vector<std::string>(26); is 26 size of the vector?

Comment: Yes, 26 is the size of the vector. When you want to map single alphabetical characters to other objects, a slick way to do it is to create an array with the length of the alphabet. Doing `array[letter - 'A']` will access the slot that represents the letter `letter`. Characters in C++ use the ASCII table, where letters are represented as numbers internally. All characters including the alphabetical letters can be used as numbers, so doing `letter - 'A'` where `letter == 'A'` makes it `'A' - 'A'` which is 0, then if `letter == 'B'` it is '1' and so on.

Comment: If I wanted to use string instead of letter. How should I have implemented then ? Hello str:1 instead of Hello A:1

Comment: @CarlosErmani Instead of `vector<string>` you would use `unordered_map<string, string>` and make a few more modifications.

Comment: Either `unordered_map` or `map` if you care about order.